# Unirest not creating json string properly

Tags: unirest

I have created a small REST API and wanted to consume it in Java. I added Unirest to my POM file and tried the most simple example, but it won't work.

```
        try {
        HttpResponse<JsonNode> jsonResponse = Unirest.post(URL + "employees/comments")
                .header("accept", "application/json")
                .field("text", "Good job")
                .field("timestamp", "123455677777")
                .field("senderId", "5")
                .field("receiverId", "2")
                .asJson();

    } catch (UnirestException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This throws an exception:

```
com.mashape.unirest.http.exceptions.UnirestException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.json.JSONException: A JSONArray text must start with '[' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
```

As far as I understand, something is wrong with the json formatting, though should unirest deal with that? http://unirest.io/java.html